# How do I echo a command and include line returns?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

I am writing a bash script, and on a condition I'd like to output `ps aux --sort -rss`

However, when I write :

```
echo `ps aux --sort -rss`
```

everything is on one huge line. How do I run it so it outputs like it normally does in a terminal?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just running `ps aux --sort -rss`?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: I was using it in a script for a cron job. After you made your comment i probably could just call ps in the bash script and it would work as expected? I just edited my script and confirmed that it worked. +1 for your comment. I guess i'll use the accepted answer when i want to build and string and output it as one line

Comment: If it does work fine without `echo`, somebody did submit that as an [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24893/how-do-i-echo-a-command-and-include-line-returns/24900#24900)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek yes but that doesnt answer my question. In this case i should be doing it that way but it still doesnt answer the question (if i accepted it, the title of the question would be misleading. But leave it please)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quote the command:

```
echo "`ps aux --sort -rss`"
```

Otherwise bash just parses the tokens, ignoring whitespace including newlines like it does when you type it by hand.

Comment: You're invoking a sub shell to issue a command that doesn't require a sub shell.

Comment: @PaulTomblin I'm answering the question that was asked, how to get it to echo with the newlines.  I don't know why he wants to do it this way, but it doesn't matter for correctly answering the question.

Comment: @PaulTomblin if you -1 him can you please undo it

Comment: Why should I undo it?  It's the wrong way to get a `ps` result in the output of a bash script.  Just because you accepted the answer doesn't make it right.

Comment: @PaulTomblin: Then you should -1 me because thats exactly what i am asking

Comment: Sometimes the right answer is "DON'T DO IT THE WAY YOU'RE ASKING HOW TO DO IT".  Sometimes the people answering you know better than you do - that's why they're answering and you're asking.

Comment: @PaulTomblin: ok fine but thats why people can leave comments and someone did. In this case its better to not use echo but i am using this script for a cronjob. I could easily just grab the free ram, CPU % usage and HD space every few 3 hours. If i want the result to be in a single line i would use the answer kevin specified and that is exactly what i asked.

Answer (score 13):

Get rid of the echo entirely, and just issue the command

```
ps aux --sort -rss
```